# How can I run SSH as a different user on the same Ubuntu installation?

Tags: ssh, root, git

I am creating a script which runs a series of command that would download a website to a machine and sets up everything.

So most of the commands require root access. For example adding a vhost in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, enabling it, restarting apache, etc...

So in order to do that, I need to run the script with `sudo`.

```
sudo ./install-website.sh
```

The website is located on a server with a git repository which is setup with a password-less SSH access. But that only works for the user `dan` since the keys are in my home folder and not in the root's home folder.

So when it reaches this part:

```
git clone user@host.com:git-repo $PATH_TO_INSTALLATION
```

Since I started the script with `sudo`, the user that is trying to initiate the git command is root. So the host keeps asking for the host's user's password.

I have tried the following command:

```
sudo -u $SUDO_USER git clone user@host.com:git-repo $PATH_TO_INSTALLATION
```

But it was still asking for the host's user's password.

Is it possible to tell `sudo` to use the `$SUDO_USER`'s home path?

Most of the stuff are variables, and have to be variables as I will run this on more than 1 machine.

Comment: I guessed you try that: `git clone dan@host.com:....` why does it not work?

Comment: Preferred way would be to add root `id_rsa.pub` key to `authorized_keys` on `host.com` system. So in case the one of clonning machines need to have access revoked, just remove it's key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Alternative 1 - Configuring sudo

Sudo is configure in the `sudoers` file which you should only edit through the `visudo` command.

This configuration file can override certain environment variables with the option `env_reset`. How to proceed:

```
visudo
```

Then find a line that states:

```
Defaults env_reset
```

and add after it (e.g. example with the HOME environement):

```
Defaults env_keep = "HOME"
```

This example is for every sudo configuration you may have. You can also specify it on a per user/group basis. See [sudoers manual page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html).

### Alternative 2 - configuring SSH

You can use the configuration file of SSH to specify users, key to use, etc. I have explain that at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/442917/53206).

Proposed solution (but you will have to correct the missing and assumed bits), edit the file `/root/.ssh/config` and set its permission `chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/config`:

```
Host host.com
  User dan
  IdentityFile /home/dan/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then as root, you can do the next command and it will use the proper SSH identifications:

```
git clone host.com:git-repo $PATH_TO_INSTALLATION
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to modify system configurations to make the script work, as I want to run on multiple machines and prefer not to configure all of them.

Comment: Then you should be able to use alternative 2, there is no default `.ssh/config` file, so you can ship one with your script or create one from your script. You can see that in this file you can explicitly specify where you stored your generated ssh key, no need to have it in a default location.

Comment: I've been trying this solution for a while and trying to fix anything that might be wrong. But I keep getting the following error: `/root/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: IdentifyFile`

Comment: You have a typo it is not `IdentifyFile` but `IdentityFile` :-)

Comment: I think it's time to have my eyes checked ! Thanks it works

Answer (score 3):

Since the script is running as root, it can `su` straight to the unpriviliged user. Roots don't need to `sudo`, `sudo` is for lusers ;-).

Assuming the unprivileged user is `dan`, and $PATH_TO_INSTALLATION is set in the surrounding script:

```
su -lc "git clone user@host.com:git-repo $PATH_TO_INSTALLATION" dan
```

Note that `$PATH_TO_INSTALLATION` must be writable by `dan`.

Comment: This also keeps asking me for the host's user's password

Comment: @Dan But not when you execute this as `dan`? Note the `-l` argument to `su`, to make sure you get a login shell, in `dan`'s home.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it as it is. I even tried the following command thinking maybe it might be a git issue. `su -lc "ssh user@host.com" dan`. It also asked me for a password.

Comment: And when you login to a console (not the GUI), as dan, after a fresh restart (so no ssh-agent is caching anything), and you do "ssh user@host.com", you are *not* asked for a password?

Comment: I assume you have a passwordless private key file in .ssh, correct? Have you tried using the `-i` argument to `ssh`, to explicitly tell it which private key file it should use?

Comment: Ok this was the problem, I wasn't using the default id_rsa name for my key. I had it with a different name. After I changed it to id_rsa it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

When I generated my ssh key a long time ago with `ssh-keygen`, I didn't choose the default path `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Thanks to [zwets](https://askubuntu.com/users/134479/zwets)' [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267696/how-can-i-run-ssh-as-a-different-user-on-the-same-ubuntu-installation#comment335435_267702), I remmebered that. I changed my key, and put it in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Now both of the commands work:

1. With `sudo`

   ```
   sudo -u $SUDO_USER git clone user@host.com:git-repo $PATH_TO_INSTALLATION
   ```
2. As suggested in [zwets' answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/267702/8698)

   ```
   su -lc "git clone user@host.com:git-repo $PATH_TO_INSTALLATION" $SUDO_USER
   ```